# ko.mapping.fromJS destroys array members

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I need to populate my model with data using `ko.mapping.fromJS`. When I run the following snippet (http://jsfiddle.net/XBYhv/), everything is fine: `people.firstName` is updated, and new `prop2` property is added to the model.

```
var Person = function() {
        this.lastName = ko.observable('lastName');
        this.firstName = ko.observable('firstName');
    };

var DataModel = function() {
        this.people = ko.observable(new Person());
        this.prop1 = ko.observable('prop1');
    };

var vm = function(){
    this.data = new DataModel();
    this.log = function(){
        console.log(this.data, this.data.people());
    };
    this.update = function(){
        ko.mapping.fromJS(
            {
                people: { firstName: 'firstName updated'},
                prop2: 'prop2'
            }
            ,{}, this.data);
    }
 };

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Then I want to slightly change the model by turning `people` into array (http://jsfiddle.net/XBYhv/1/):

```
. . .
this.people = ko.observableArray([new Person()]);
. . .
ko.mapping.fromJS({
                people: [{ firstName: 'firstName updated'}],
. . .
```

And now the bad thing happens: `people` object is destroyed and replaced with `[{ firstName: 'firstName updated'}]`, losing `lastName` instead of just updating `firstName`.

Anyone can shed some light on the reasons of such behavior, and the correct way to update model in this case?

Answer (score 0):

This case is described in [the docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html#customizing_object_construction_using_create): to map objects (i.e. properties of your VM which are objects) you usually need to instruct `ko.mapping` how to create (or compare) these objects, e.g. by providing `create` function:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(
    {
        people: [{ firstName: 'firstName updated'}]
    }
    ,{
        'people': {
            create: function (options) {
                return new Person(options.data)
            }
        }
    }, this.data);
```

See the following fiddle for solution: http://jsfiddle.net/XBYhv/2/